# Charging a 3.7 V Li-ion cell and boosting to 5 V output

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, lithium-ion, boost, esp32

I am trying to find a board that will support charging a 3.7 V Li-ion pouch cell and also boost the output to 5 V in order to power a ESP32 board.

I would like to keep it in the loop with the rest of the components so that the project doesn't have to be taken apart to charge the battery. That being said, if it would power the system from the charging source while charging the cell, that would be ideal.

Most boards I found are labeled for 18650 cells. I also wonder if these would charge your typical 3.7 V pouch cell.

Comment: A Power Bank is already made and sold. It has a 5V USB input jack for charging the Li-Ion or Li-PO battery cell inside, and a voltage booster to provide regulated 5V output. If you try making it yourself you must select a charger circuit and a voltage booster circuit that do not overpower the battery causing to explode.

Answer (score 2):

Please understand that a Li-ion pouch cell (which you call a "li-po") operates internally the same as a 18650 Li-ion cell. It's the same chemistry, just in a different package. The package makes little difference to a charger, to a BMS, and to a load. A 3.7 V Li-ion cell is a 3.7 V Li-ion cell, regardless of the package. So, yes, any 3.7 V Li-ion charger will work on a 3.7 V Li-ion cell, whether pouch, small cylindrical, prismatic, etc.

This table gives the full picture.

[image: Li-ion cell table]